# Django && hadoop

Tags: django, hadoop, hdfs

I just want to access the hdfs from web with django,so I use the hadoopy,I just write

```
def list(reqeust):
    return HttpResponse(hadoopy.ls("."))
```

in views.py,but something is wrong,there are some informations about the error:`"IOError at /list/ Ran[hadoop fs -ls .]: /bin/sh: 1: hadoop: not found"`,I think the "hadoop" command can't be resolved by shell,but I don't know what to do

Comment: Can you run the `hadoop` command from shell? Hadoopy needs a functional Hadoop cluster on the machine it is run on. Is it your case? If not maybe it would be better to use [Hoop - HDFS over HTTP](http://cloudera.github.com/hoop/docs/latest/index.html). It provides a REST API to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

The `hadoopy` library you're attempting to use is simply acting as a wrapper over the existing Apache Hadoop bash command scripts (`hadoop`, `hdfs`, `mapred`, etc. commands) and thereby requires those to be installed and available on your OS's or Application's `PATH` env-var, so it may call a `hadoop fs -ls <path>` shell command when you attempt to do `hadoopy.ls(…)`.